# Elaboration results in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I've a simple GUI Java application. When I click on SEARCH button, the search class makes a search in many documents.

The application has a `System.out.println` that works perfectly (writes a line when a document is found) but it doesn't add a line to the `JLabel` at the same time.

The `JLabel` of results is updated only at the end of research.

The two instructions are consecutive

```
System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + strPath);

this.aPHtResponseMsg.appendNL((i+1) + ". " + strPath);

/* this one write into JLabel with setText method after elaborating the string, so I use a particular class*/
```

Is it a "strange" behavior of Java GUI?
Have I made any mistake into logic?

Comment: Use a SwingWorker to do the search part in a background thread, and publish progress that updates the Swing UI. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: Nothing strange about it -- you're locking the GUI's event thread by doing long-processing on it. Look at @JBNizet's link and also at the entire tutorial which contains that link as a sub-section: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly :)